# How accurate is BigDecimal.doubleValue() if no operation is applied on the amount

Tags: java, soap, double, precision, bigdecimal

I NEED to be sending a value as '**double**', however I am:

1. *Taking* a value as a **long**
2. *Converting* it to **BigDecimal**
3. Calling method **scaleByPowerOfTen** on the *BigDecimal* (using '-2' to make cents a whole amount value).
4. Calling **doubleValue()** on the *BigDecimal* to get the needed value as **double**.

Now I know that *double* values lose precision when you apply arithmetic operations on them, **however what could I possibly get** if I try to send a double value as-is based on BigDecimal, such as (I believe) the above scenario is.

This is important as I have to be sending money values over SOAP in this manner - no other way.

I also have the scenario where the *BigDecimal* is created using as a **String**, then **doubleValue()** is called on it. **What could I get in this case ?**

EDIT:
Sample code for this:

```
long amountInCents = 1852;
BigDecimal amountInWholeUnits = BigDecimal.valueOf(amountInCents).scaleByPowerOfTen(-2);
double amountToSend = amountInWholeUnits.doubleValue();
```

As for the case where the amount is provided as String:

```
double amountToSend = new BigDecimal("18.52").doubleValue();
```

### UPDATE

Now that I have sample code, I just thought I can test and see, so I did a **for** loop and used **System.out.println**: so far so good, the values are correct, so I believe this will be the same when sent through SOAP. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Could you add a simple code example?

Answer (score 1):

Since one cent is equal to 1/100 of a dollar, and since the number 1/100 or `0.01` *cannot* be represented exactly as a binary floating-point number, some slight loss of accuracy will occur. In your particular example of $18.52, the resulting `double` will hold the closest `double` value to 18.52, but it will *not* be exactly equal to 18.52.

Comment: However, as far as I'm concerned, this doesn't affect the value sent to the web service, as in XML a double will become a String.

Comment: If you're sending XML, then just convert the BigDecimal directly to a String and send that.

Comment: Actually sending a SOAP request using service generated stub code. So I am forced to send a double value by Code.

Comment: In that case, you have absolutely no control over the precision of the number sent, because the way the `double` you give that service is converted to a String is entirely defined by the implementation of the service itself.

Comment: @united-expression If a service tries to handle monetary values as `double`, and not as `BigDecimal` or even `String`, then there is inherently a design flaw with that service or the generated stub. Most likely you wont be having a problem using the `double` as an intermediary, and errors are only noticeable as they are accumulated over multiple operations.

Comment: @JoD I do know that, but they won't update the service. As for any flaws occurring inside the service due to the double type, I don't know how it's handled internally, and frankly I am not concerned about that anymore. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @united-expression you are probably fine as long as the service avoids accumulation of the error. I would also suggest doing some tests: send a value like "3.99999" and validate that it gets rounded to 4.00, and not truncated to "3.99" - in the latter case, you might need to be burdened to try to forcefully correct that from your end.

Answer (score 0):

Java doubles are inherently approximations. In other words, **there is no guarantee that there exists a value of double that exactly corresponds to any given floating point value**.

BigDecimal does work by exactly representing a floating point value. But that means that for any valid value of BigDecimal, there is no guarantee that there exists a value of double that represents it. This is true no matter how you created the BigDecimal.

If you need an exact representation of an amount, you can't use double. You will need to keep using BigDecimal during all calculations, or find an integer representation that matches your needs. Integer numbers of cents is frequently used, but remember that calculations can sometimes involve fractions of a cent, and rounding strategies can have big effects if the calculation is done many times.

If you have no calculations to do, then using an integer (e.g. integer number of cents) to represent the value will be fine.

Comment: I don't have any calculations, the values used are exactly as seen in the example.

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenJDK implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java) of `BigDecimal` seems to achieve the natural accuracy of a `double`.

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(1852).scaleByPowerOfTen(-2);
```

creates a BigDecimal with a value of (effectively) `1852` and a `scale` of `-2`.

```
amountInWholeUnits.doubleValue();
```

checks the scale and, if it is not 0 (like in this case) it does:

```
Double.parseDouble(this.toString());
```

so essentially the results of the operations you are planning will be a `double` as near to `18.52` as is possible with `double`.

Obviously this also assumes that all JDKs do something similar (which may not be the case).

Comment: I'm testing using the Sun JDK, and I have reached value 99999.99 without any precision loss.